# Accessing a pointer in Swift/Obj-c to Swift Conversion with pointers

Tags: objective-c, swift

Im trying to do the following in Swift:

```
CFArrayRef attachmentsArray = CMSampleBufferGetSampleAttachmentsArray(sampleBuffer, 0);
    if (CFArrayGetCount(attachmentsArray)) {
        CFBooleanRef notSync;
        CFDictionaryRef dict = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(attachmentsArray, 0);
        BOOL keyExists = CFDictionaryGetValueIfPresent(dict,
                                                   kCMSampleAttachmentKey_NotSync,
                                                   (const void **)&notSync);
```

I have:

```
if CFArrayGetCount(attachmentsArray) != 0 {
    let dict = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(attachmentsArray, 0)
```

However, dict is a  UnsafePointer instead of a dictionary like it should be. When I printed attachmentsArray I got

`Optional({ DependsOnOthers = 0; })`

I tried casting it to a CFDictionaryRef but it would fail in runtime.
How do I succeed in doing the above Obj-C code in Swift?

Answer (score 3):

> However, dict is a UnsafePointer instead of a dictionary like it should be.

No, not "like it should be". Look at the declaration:

```
func CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(theArray: CFArray!, _ idx: CFIndex) 
    -> UnsafePointer<Void>
```

It returns an UnsafePointer-to-void because that is what it is supposed to do. (In Objective-C it returns a `const void *`.)

Comment: May I ask why you are working in the CFArray world? A CFArray is bridged to NSArray, and NSArray is bridged to Swift Array. This would be a lot easier to do if you just crossed the darned bridge!

Comment: I guess I was not clear when I said "However, dict is a UnsafePointer instead of a dictionary like it should be." What I meant was that although it returns a pointer, the pointer points to a dictionary which is what I want access to (in the Obj-C version they were able to define the pointer as a CFDictionaryRef but I can't do so).

About why I'm working in the CFArray world: Actually i'm not sure... I guess i should attempt to convert the array up there instead of the pointer later on, I'll try that and let you know.

Comment: Converted via:

    let attachmentsArray = unsafeBitCast(CMSampleBufferGetSampleAttachmentsArray(buffer, 0), [AnyObject].self)

Not sure if this is correct practice or not and it seems to have mutated the array into holding nothing instead of Optional({ DependsOnOthers = 0; }), so I'm not sure if that is good either. However, since it still doesn't hold the key, I guess I don't need to worry about it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: "I guess i should attempt to convert the array" There is nothing to convert. As I already said, CFArray _is_ an NSArray, which is bridged to Swift Array, and now you are talking pure Swift.

Comment: Kinda confused. AFAIK, the type CFArray is not the same as an NSArray. How did you make CFArray into an NSArray?

Comment: "AFAIK, the type CFArray is not the same as an NSArray" Then you know wrong. They are toll-free bridged, I keep telling you. They are _exactly_ the same thing. Read the fifth paragraph on this page: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFArrayRef/

Comment: Ok that's cool... how does one index into a CFArray? array[0] or array.objectAtIndex(0) doesn't seem to work for me on this one.

I'm not trying to be difficult here but for some reason, if I don't use the unsafeBitCast, my compiler complains when I do stuff like array.count or array[0]/array.objectAtIndex(0).

Comment: You don't. You cast it to an NSArray and to an Array of some sort and _now_ you index into it. That's my point. Why speak the difficult CFArray language when it is so easy to speak the NSArray / Array language?

Comment: So, I cast via unsafeBitCast? (which is what I asked above).

Yes I agree that I shouldn't be using CFArray if I can correctly change it to NSArray/Array. I just don't know if I'm doing it right.

Comment: You cast with `as`. You _might_ be able to cast with `as! [[NSObject:AnyObject]]` — I am pretty sure this thing is an array of dictionaries. Unfortunately I have no buffer to experiment with.

Comment: The as cast didn't work for me... oh well thanks for the help

Comment: You couldn't cast `attachmentsArray` to an array?

Comment: attachmentsArray as! [AnyObject] nor attachmentArray as! NSArray([AnyObject])
I don't know if those are correct casting. I might just be doing it wrong.

Comment: According to the docs, `attachmentsArray` should be a `CFArray?` (an Optional wrapping a CFArray). So I would expect to be able to say `if let cfarr = attachmentsArray {let arr = cfarr as NSArray; // ...}` and work with `arr` as an ordinary array. I'm sorry I can't test on my own machine.